# Finding circumference of a "circle" in the new coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems

Transformation  $$x=a\cosh u \cos v,\quad y=a \sinh u \sin v$$

the line element $$ds^2=dx^2+dy^2=a^2(\sinh^2 u+\sin ^2v)(dv^2+du^2)$$

The exercise asks the circumference of the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ (i.e. in (u,v) coordinates $\sinh^2u+\cos^2 v=1$)

It is an exercise from Einstein's general relativity book by Hartle.

I realy don't understand physicists' notation. I cannot use jacobian formalization or differential geometric idea because the question is a little bit ill-defined to me.

In general:

Circumference:= $\displaystyle\oint ds=\oint dx\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$

I dont know how to write $(dy/dx)$ and where I should take this integral for given $u,v$ above.

Comment: *I realy don't understand physicists' notation* In which notation are you looking for an answer?

Comment: It would help if you quoted the text of the exercise, or at least told us what exercise it is. Right now the question is a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually it is rather straightforward, however, implies some computations.
The circumference $C$ is:

$$C=\oint ds = \oint a \sqrt{\sinh^2 u + \sin^2 v}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{du}{dv}\right)^2} dv $$

Because of  $\sinh^2 u + \cos^2 v =1$ via $\sinh^2 u = \sin^2 v$  we can already simplify:

$$C =a \oint \sqrt{2\sin^2 v}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{du}{dv}\right)^2} dv$$

Moreover we have: 
$$u=u(v)=\sinh^{-1}(\sin v)\quad\text{so}\quad\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{\cos v}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2v}}$$

Finally we get:

$$C=a\sqrt{2}\oint\sqrt{ \frac{\sin^2 v (1+ \sin^2 v) + \sin^2 v \cos^2 v}{1+ \sin^2 v}} dv=2a\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\frac{\sin^2 v}{1+\sin^2 v}} dv$$

The last integral has to be split into 2 parts:

$$C=2a \int_0^{\pi} |\sin(v)| \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\sin^2 v}} dv + \int_\pi^{2\pi} |\sin(v)|\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\sin^2 v}} dv =2a \int_0^{\pi} \sin(v) \sqrt{\frac{1}{2-\cos^2 v}} dv -\int\limits_\pi^{2\pi} \sin(v)\sqrt{\frac{1}{2-\cos^2 v}} dv$$

It can be evaluated with the substitution: $t=\cos(v)$, therefore $-dt =\sin(v) dv$, so we get:

$$C=-2a \int_1^{-1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(\sqrt{2})^2 - t^2}} + 2a \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(\sqrt{2})^2 - t^2}} = 4a \int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(\sqrt{2})^2 - t^2}} = 4a \arcsin(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})|^{1}_{-1}= 8a\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}=2\pi a$$

which shows that the circumference has the same value independent of the chosen coordinates.